# file type html document (text/html) is not supported

Tags: python, pdf, download

I have to download multiple pdf files and I do not have their direct download links. What I have is the link for the html page on which the download link is available. For example this link:

https://www.astrazeneca.com/sustainability.html

If you visit this link, there are two pdf download links available (https://www.astrazeneca.com/content/dam/az/Sustainability/2020/pdf/Sustainability_Report_2019.pdf, https://www.astrazeneca.com/content/dam/az/Sustainability/2020/pdf/Sustainability_Data_Summary_2019.pdf). I have to actually download those but I do not have these links in my hand.

How can I extract these download links?

One more example link that I have:
http://www.mtr.com.hk/sustainability/2017rpt/en/corporate/sustainability/2017rpt/home.php

Comment: You get that message where exactly and from what? What is the raw content of the file you have downloaded?

Comment: The file is empty, this error is coming as prompt when I am opening the file.

Comment: You’re opening the file how? With a PDF reader? Have you looked at the raw contents of what you downloaded with a text editor? Please show your code.

Comment: I am opening the file using document viewer in linux. In text editor, html code is coming. And I have used every single code from the links mentioned in the question.

for instance:
import requests

url = 'https://de.calameo.com/read/003424018906cfa7ff072'
response = requests.get(url)


with open('saved_pdf.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)

Comment: What is the HTML code saying? What page did you fetch there?

Comment: That is the HTML code for this page: https://de.calameo.com/read/003424018906cfa7ff072

Comment: Yeah, that link *is* an actual HTML page, a web viewer for a PDF of some sorts. Is there an actual link to an actual PDF somewhere…? Is your problem how to find that link from that page…?

Comment: yes, I have to download pdf files from links like these only which are not direct download links. I understood now that first I have to find the download link from the page. Could you please help me out here?

Comment: First confirm such a link exists somewhere and where to find it. Perhaps there’s already a simple discernible pattern behind those links, so you just need to alter the URL you’re downloading slightly. Otherwise, if you need to locate a link on that HTML page programmatically, you’ll want to use an HTML parser like beautifulsoup4. If you need help with that, give more details about the exact HTML and where exactly you’re stuck locating the link within it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214393/discussion-between-lucky-sunda-and-deceze).